# How do i set the AutoFocusCallback and set FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_VIDEO in OpenCV Camera?

Tags: opencv, android-camera, android

Good day! 
I am currently using OpenCV4Android in my application, and i wanted to set the AutoFocusCallback and FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_VIDEO on the camera, but all i have is just the CameraBridgeViewBase object with an org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView on the layout. so how do i set them?